# How to join three table to check the data in sql?

Tags: mysql

I know how to join two tables to check data, but I not sure how to join the third table. I have tried to find solution in the online, but I can't find solution it can match my problem. Hope someone can guide me how to join the third table. Thanks.

Below is my sql code, this sql code just to join two tables:

```
SELECT bl.id_book_name as bl_book_name
     , bl.remark as bl_remark
     , bl.status as status
     , bl.return_date as bl_return_date
     , anb.country as anb_country
     , anb.title as book_name
     , bl.date_borrowed as date_borrowed 
  FROM book_lending bl 
  JOIN add_new_book anb 
    ON bl.id_book_name = anb.id
```

My third table column in the below, table name is called `user`, I want to join the `user` name:

```html
id |name |
```

This is my join two tables testing result:

[image: output 1]

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expcted  result as tabular data

Comment: Show CREATE TABLE scripts for all 3 tables, including FKs. If FKs are absent then specify the relations between tables.

Comment: what is the schema of the three tables

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have not provided the full structure of USER table, I can only provide you the glimpse of joining third table. You may try below code -

```
SELECT bl.id_book_name as bl_book_name
     , bl.remark as bl_remark
     , bl.status as status
     , bl.return_date as bl_return_date
     , anb.country as anb_country
     , anb.title as book_name
     , bl.date_borrowed as date_borrowed 
  FROM book_lending bl 
  JOIN add_new_book anb ON bl.id_book_name = anb.id
  JOIN user u ON u.id = <USER_ID column in 1 of above 2 tables>
```